How do I interpret the time axis in a diagram with multiple light cones?
Light cones are often drawn on a spacetime diagram that has a directional time axis like the fourth one on this page:

There is a time axis, and all of the light cones are align with it because this diagram depicts a flat spacetime.
When depicted in curved spacetime, the light cones tilt at varying angles (according to the curvature of spacetime) as in the fifth and sixth diagrams here.

Yet a time axis that is perfectly vertical and pointing up is included in the diagrams. What does this axis mean in this context? There is no one time direction, right?

Time is a local concept generally different for every observer. The axis on your second diagram is the time of a remote observer only. The time axis of other observers is represented by the axis of every light cone.

If you imagine the second diagram drawn on a thin sheet of rubber, you could stretch it to make all light cones vertical just like on the first diagram. This is exactly how Penrose diagrams are drawn. All light cones on a Penrose diagram are vertical regardless of the spacetime curvature.

It's nice to hear that explicitly! Thanks.

The light cones mark the trajectories of light that either originates from an event in spacetime (the future light cone) or arrives at the event (the past light cone).
In flat spacetime these are cones with a 45 degree half opening angle, aligned with the temporal axis.
In curved spacetime light trajectories are not necessarily at 45 degrees to the temporal axis and neither do the light cones need to be aligned with that axis. The coordinates plotted are just one choice for one particular observer.
What is true, is that locally, and drawn in the coordinates measured by an observer in that local inertial frame, the light cones look like those of Special Relativity. But drawn in some global coordinate system, the light cones may be tilted and have some other opening angle.
One cannot generalise here. The temporal axis is usually chosen to represent some coordinate, which when incremented positively produces a timelike interval, but that still leaves plenty of choice. Your second diagram looks like the temporal axis could be in Gullstrand-Painleve coordinates, where the time axis would be that measured on the clock of a free falling observer from infinity.

It is probably the spacetime diagram drawn by an "asymptotic observer".
